# React Router - useNavigation based upon last Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to do something very simple in a React app. I want a "Back" button to take the user to the previous page UNLESS the user has arrived from a specific page, and in that case "Back" will route them to a different page - something like:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

    if (lastPage === XYZ) {
        navigate('/home');
    } else {
        navigate(-1);
    }
```

My issue is that I can't work out how to get hold of the lastPage  in react-router-dom v6 (where useHistory has been depricated).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "specific" page you should send some "state" to indicate that's where it navigated from.

Example:

- Using `Link` component

  ```
  <Link to="/newPage" state={{ fromSpecificPage: true }} />
  ```
- Using `Navigate` component

  ```
  <Navigate to="/newPage" state={{ fromSpecificPage: true }} />
  ```
- Using `navigate` function

  ```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate("/newPage", { state: { fromSpecificPage: true } });
  ```

Then on the page you want to conditionally handle the back navigation check this specific route state that was possibly passed.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { state } = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...
const { fromSpecificPage } = state || {};
if (fromSpecificPage) {
  navigate('/home', { replace: true });
} else {
  navigate(-1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the super quick and clear response. Implemented and works great. I thought that there would be some history record I could query, but this passed state solution was easier to use than I had expected!

Comment: @redPanda The previous versions of RRD were partial abstractions over the `window` history APIs, in RRDv6 it's effectively a full abstraction over them. Even in the previous versions you didn't have full access to the history stack so you would've needed to maintain your own in-memory history if you wanted to query the previous page. This OFC requires more moving parts to implement and use than just passing a tiny bit of state in the route transition.